# How to access a text file in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, io, windows-forms-designer, file-handling, windows

I have added a text file into Windows form Application and trying to access this file.

Here is my code..

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        System.String s = Application.StartupPath+"/Licence.txt";
        System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(s);

        if (fi.Exists)
        {
            if (fi.Length == 0)
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }
    }
```

Licence.txt is there in my project folder but every time (fi.Exists) comes to be false only and program comes out of the flow without showing Form1() window..
Please Help me.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `Application.StartupPath+@"\Licence.txt"`? Change the frontslash to a backslash

Comment: As Ben said, plus: the file is in your project folder, but is it also in your output folder ("Copy to Output Directory)?

Comment: This is why it's important to master debugging. Just set a breakpoint on the `fi.Exists` line and check the Fileinfo path. Copy it into windows explorer and see if the file is actually there. Chances are, it's not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
string s = Path.Combine(
  Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
  "Licence.txt");
```

Do not try to combine paths manually because you must deal with path delimiters... using builtin functions is much better!

Finally remember to set `Copy to Output` property on *License.txt* file inside your project.

Answer (score 1):

Without doing a string concatenation use [Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
System.String s = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"Licence.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

[1] The question is where it is in your project folder :) Application.StartupPath gets in debug mode

> yourProject\bin\Debug

is your file there?

try step-by-step debugging and look which path you get and if the file is there

[2] Your Window is not shown, because you missed adding

> Application.Run(new yourForm());

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

string filePath = Path.GetFullPath("Licence.txt");

This file should present inside installation folder. So that you can get filepath.